# How to make this special View - com.android.colorpicker.ColorPickerPalette?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use this library right here but i'm finding some difficulties, please give me a hand - https://materialdoc.com/components/pickers/#color-picker . It is giving me this error which I can't seem to find a way to do:
 - Required: com.android.colorpicker.ColorPickerPalett - So far I have this: I'm getting the error when i try to inflate the view.

```
    int[] color_array = this.getResources().
            getIntArray(R.array.default_color_choice_values);

    ColorPickerDialog colorPickerDialog = new ColorPickerDialog();
    colorPickerDialog.initialize(
            R.string.color_picker_default_title, color_array, 0, 2, color_array.length);

    colorPickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "cal");

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    ColorPickerPalette colorPickerPalette = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_picker, null);

    ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener mOnColorSelectedListener = new ColorPickerSwatch.OnColorSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onColorSelected(int color) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Will fill the code later on");
        }
    };
    colorPickerPalette.init(color_array.length, 3, mOnColorSelectedListener);

    colorPickerPalette.drawPalette(color_array, 0);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_picker, null);` will be of type ColorPallet ONLY IF your root tag at xml (custom_picker) is exactly `<com.android.colorpicker.ColorPickerPalette ....`

Else, if you have LinearLayout or any other ViewGroup you must change your code to find the inner view (assuming you have the tag of the picker a @+id)

```
 ViewGroup resultLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_picker, null);
 ColorPickerPalette colorPickerPalette = resultLayout.findViewById(R.id.color_picker_id_at_xml);
```

Comment: That's perfect and is there a way to embed it so it won't be a dialog and it will be showing all the time?? And also for some reason all the colours are black :))

Comment: Don't use the ColorPickerDialog, you will have to add the components trough XML, you have to add your one in the question